# I want to place a button above SKCanvasView on the full screen

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, maps, skiasharp

Images are displayed (full screen) with SKCanvasView.
I want to put controls such as buttons there, but it is displayed at startup, but it disappears when the image is displayed.!

[image]

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if it helps you so that we can help more people with same problem:)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [absolute-layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout) to layout the controls:

```
public TileAlignmentPage()
{
    Title = "Tile Alignment";
    var layout = new AbsoluteLayout();

    SKCanvasView canvasView = new SKCanvasView();
    canvasView.PaintSurface += OnCanvasViewPaintSurface;
    ...
    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(canvasView, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1));
    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(canvasView, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);

    Button clear_button = new Button { Text = "-" };
    ...
    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(clear_button, new Rectangle(0.5, 0.45, 250, 50));
    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(clear_button, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);

    Button update_button = new Button { Text = "+" };
    ...
    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(update_button, new Rectangle(0.5, 0.55, 250, 50));
    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(update_button, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);

    layout.Children.Add(canvasView);
    layout.Children.Add(clear_button);
    layout.Children.Add(update_button);
    Content = layout;
}
```